# OSGI with Hibernate: "No suitable driver found"

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, osgi, equinox

I'm getting the beloved error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/acme
```

I understand many reasons why this error usually arises:

- **Invalid URL:** This URL doesn't seem to have any errors in it and works perfectly fine in SQL Workbench.
- **Driver Not on ClassPath:** It is successfully imported (org.postgresql.Driver) and can be instantiated either directly or by using Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").

The Hibernate `SessionFactory` loading is initiated from a Spring-Bean but is carried out at runtime with the following properties:

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/acme
hibernate.connection.username = user
hibernate.connection.password = pass
```

I understand that the Java `DriverManager` does not work in OSGi, so registering the driver with the `DriverManager` or instantiating it to force it to register has no effect.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Is there a common solution?

Thanks in advance!

---

**The Solution**

As pointed out by Andres Olarte, I made a mistake of adding the driver to the *implementation bundle*, but leaving it out of the *Hibernate bundle* where Hibernate's classes and dependencies reside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you have this packaged?  If you put the Hibernate and the Postgresql JDBC jar in the same OSGi bundle, it should work.  This is what BIRT does load its jdbc drivers.

Comment: They are in two separate bundles, but there is no problem with referencing them or instantiating them so I can't see this being the problem...?

Comment: Can you add code in Hibernate bundle to access the class in the PostgreSQL bundle? You might be able to access classes in the Hibernate and PostgreSQL bundle from a third bundle, but that doesn't mean that the Hibernate bundle will be able to access the class in the PostgreSQL bundle.  The Hibernate bundle will be able to access the class in the PostgreSQL if it's aware of it. Does it make sense?

Comment: It's likely this is the problem since I don't recall making any changes to the Hibernate bundle since adding the PostgreSQL driver and as you guessed my Hibernate SessionFactory is in a third bundle! I will look at this on Monday and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Andres, this was exactly the problem! Can't believe that I missed something so small, it really can be a steep learning curve on OSGi. Can you also update your answer to reflect this. Thanks again.