# Using Spring 3.x AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in Eclipse RCP

Tags: spring, eclipse-rcp, osgi, dependency-management

I have a server based component wired up using Spring.  I have a client interface that also uses Spring to connect to the server.  I need to connect to the server from an Eclipse RCP application.

I have included the required spring libraries in my target platform.

However, when I try to create the Spring context, I get a ClassNotFoundException on "net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer" which results in an IllegalStateException being thrown.

I have manually wrapped cglib 2.2 in a plugin and added that to my target platform, but it still throws the same error.

How do I ensure the Spring modules have access to CGLib?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping cglib inside your actual application bundle with it on the BundleClasspath? ie. not in a separate bundle.  And embedding it using (Embed-Dependency).

Or you can import all of the cglib library (using Private-Import) and ensure that the package shows in the bundle/jar.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple bundles, ensure that the actual bundle that needs cglib is importing it. I made this mistake recently with an Hibernate bundle and a database driver (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013205/osgi-with-hibernate-no-suitable-driver-found). I think its easy to get confused when you're used to Java's standard class loading.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in by creating a separate bundle containing Spring and all the required dependencies.  I then had to add Eclipse-Buddy classloading between my client code and the spring bundle so that it could load my config classes.

Is there a better way?